# SSRS 2016 grouped Report loading very slow in Chrome

Tags: javascript, sql-server, google-chrome, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a SSRS-2016 report that is loading approx. 12000 rows that are grouped in 3 levels (the data is shown on the 3rd level). For some reason the loading of the data needs very long (approx. 3 minutes vs. some seconds in other browsers)  when using Chrome while other browsers (IE, Firefox) load in normal time. It needs such a long time that the Script-warning-popup is shown several times but if I choose "wait" the report is loaded after some time.

When I compare the entries of loading the report in different browsers in the table *ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLogStorage* the loading times are almost the same. So it is not caused by the database/queries.

After checking the loading process using Chrome Performance Profile I can see a **huge amount of time needed for scripting/some sorting operations** as can be seen here:
[Chrome Performance Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEICr.png)

When I remove the grouping the report is loaded in an acceptable time.

When I decrase the amount of data (by setting date-filters) the report is loaded in an acceptable time.

I have updated the SQL Server as well as the SSRS to the latest version but this did not help.

There are some Chrome Extensions for SSRS-fixes available but they handle another issue.

Any suggestions on how to handle this issue?